# Не отображается background-image на iphone X

Tags: css, iphone

Подскажите, что не так. Не отображается фоновая картинка(планы этажа), заданная с помощью background-image. Не работает на iphone X. Сайт: http://test29.ru/t/

Css так задается:

```css
#floors .svg-wrap {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 70.63%;
  position: relative;
}

#floors svg.f_1,
#floors svg.f_2,
#floors svg.f_3,
#floors svg.f_4,
#floors svg.f_5,
#floors svg.f_6,
#floors svg.f_7,
#floors svg.f_8,
#floors svg.f_9 {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  /* Internet Explorer 7/8 */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#floors svg.f_1 {
  background-image: url("../img/floors/1.jpg");
}

#floors svg.f_2 {
  background-image: url("../img/floors/2.jpg");
}

#floors svg.f_3 {
  background-image: url("../img/floors/3.jpg");
}

#floors svg.f_4 {
  background-image: url("../img/floors/4.jpg");
}

#floors svg.f_5 {
  background-image: url("../img/floors/5.jpg");
}

#floors svg.f_6 {
  background-image: url("../img/floors/6.jpg");
}

#floors svg.f_7 {
  background-image: url("../img/floors/7.jpg");
}

#floors svg.f_8 {
  background-image: url("../img/floors/8.jpg");
}

#floors svg.f_9 {
  background-image: url("../img/floors/9.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Читайте как браузер Safari работает с бэкграундами, там всегда есть подводные камни, наверняка и с версией X чего-нибудь намудрили они.

Comment: Только что проверил на айфон Х, все отображается как надо.